# Spring Groovy Config: import ConfigSlurper properties

Tags: spring, groovy, import, config

I'm trying to configure my Spring application using Groovy. I have several modules so the entire context is split to several `.groovy` files.

I use [suggested method](http://spring.io/blog/2014/03/03/groovy-bean-configuration-in-spring-framework-4) (section *Using External Properties*) to read properties from external file using ConfigSlurper, so in my main `context.groovy` there's `props` object defined and used:

```
def props = new ConfigSlurper("dev").parse("app.properties")    
beans {
    someBean(SomeBean) {
        commonShinyProperty = props.common.shiny
    }
}
```

Where `app.properties` is:

```
common {
    shiny = true
}
```

What I'm trying to do is to **reuse** the same properties source (`props` object) in another context part `anotherContext.groovy` — something like:

```
importBeans('classpath:context.groovy')
beans {
    anotherBean(AnotherBean) {        
        commonShinyProperty = props.common.shiny
    }
}
```

This code doesn't work as `props` is not available here, only beans from `context.groovy`. Even when it is defined as a bean, the application fails to start with errors like `Cannot get property 'shiny' on null object` or `No such property: for class...`

Please suggest if such configuration is possible. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property files are loaded through `org.springframework.boot.context.config.ConfigFileApplicationListener`, this happens before application context is really loaded.

I made a custom `GroovyPropertySource` to load `application.groovy` on classpath, so it will be available to application context through the same `Environment.getProperty()` when it needs to configure.

Check out https://github.com/davidiamyou/spring-groovy-config

You should be able to do something like

```
beans {
    anotherBean(AnotherBean) {        
        commonShinyProperty = '${common.shiny}'
    }
}
```